# Why is my APK name generic?

Tags: android-studio, apk

I'm sure this is the dumb question of the day, but here it goes...  I have an app that I need to distribute "in house" to be used by sales at a trade show.  I successfully created a self signed, zipaligned, release apk file using Android Studio (in Windows 7).  The name of the output file though is simply app-release.apk.  Why is my app name not prefixed to the output file like MyApplication-release.apk?  I suspect it has something to do with the folder structure in Android Studio where it is:  MyApplication -> app -> src -> etc,etc.  I tried refactoring the "app" folder to match my app name but it gives an error.  I'm sure I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it uses the folder name of your application's module. If you rename the folder, you also need to update your **settings.gradle** file with the updated name; the refactoring doesn't automatically change it there.

After you change **settings.gradle**, make sure you re-sync your project with the Gradle files. It should put a banner at the top of your editor windows reminding you that you need to do it; if you don't, then click the button in the toolbar.

Comment: When I first tried this it gave me an error.  The second time it worked but I had to re-sync Gradle twice after updating settings.gradle.  A little buggy but all seems fine now.

Comment: One more question.  How do I prevent this from happening in the future?  The Create New Project dialog in Android studio does not ask for the module name so it defaults to "app"

Comment: I don't think you can set it when creating a new project. You have to change it manually afterward. The fact that it doesn't update settings.gradle when you rename in the IDE is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57692

Comment: Instead of renaming module names, wouldn't it be better if the output file name is configured to contain the project name, variant and build type (and maybe a version) in the gradle build script?!

Comment: for more details (with a link to a sample project) follow http://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/producing-better-named-android-apks-with-gradle/

Answer (score 2):

May be it is too late to answer but i was having same problem to show my app name with the apk generated. i just update the `defaultConfig` in `build.gradle(Module:app)` as following

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "TestApp")
    }
```

This works by modifying the `archivesBaseName` property and works for Gradle Version >= 2.0, last tested with `gradle-3.3-all`.
Output would be `TestApp-debug.apk` instead of `app-debug.apk`