# Change generated apk name from "app-debug.apk"

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Every time I run a project with Android Studio (1.02) it's generate an unsigned apk which located in ..\build\outputs\apk folder and get by default the name "app-debug.apk"

I want to change that default name to something else.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Check this answer for new gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/67268901/8572350

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use applicationVariants and change the output file in the build.gradle. You can also modify the name regarding to your needs.

```
buildTypes{

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->                              
        variant.outputs.each { output ->                              
            output.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/apk/test.apk")
        }                                                             
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting below error while changing it. Maybe doing something wron. Please let me know. A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{variantOutput=VariantOutputImpl(versionCode=property(java.lang.Integer, provider(class java.lang.Integer)),....

Answer (score 33):

In `build.gradle` (Module: app):

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MyNewAppNameGoesHere")
    }
}
```

This works by modifying the `archivesBaseName`-property and works for Gradle Version >= 2.0, last tested with 2.1.0.

Comment: With this solution, it appends "-debug" to the name. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 13):

Solution for gradle3:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = applicationId;
        outputFileName += "-v" + android.defaultConfig.versionName;
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            outputFileName += ".apk";
        } else {
            outputFileName += "-SNAPSHOT.apk";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if anyone is confused by this code, basically you can set `outputFileName` to whatever String you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
defaultConfig {  

    applicationId "com.dcarl661.awesomelayout"

    minSdkVersion 14

    targetSdkVersion 25

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"

    //here put it in the section where you have the version stuff
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "AwesomeLayout")

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"


    def date = new Date();
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss')
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Quest_" + versionName + "_"+formattedDate)
}
```

i did like this. More detailed

Comment: this should be added to android->app->build.gradle in case of hybrid

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking to change apk name outside the Android studio(just to send this file to someone else, as in my case), just right click the app name and change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

The 'app' part of the name uses the folder name of your application's module (default is 'app'). See the link below on how to change that.
[Why is my APK name generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491040/why-is-my-apk-name-generic)

The '-debug' prefix is something you can change in the **Module settings** at **Build Types**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question (and its accepted answer) are interesting for you:
[How to set versionName in APK filename using gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18332474/3410474)
It describes how to put your versionName into the APK name.

You have to use the 'Update' part of the accepted answer. Also you need the versionName (in this example) declared in your defaultConfig in the build.gradle file. It does also work if you define versionCode in the build.gradle (as described here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries ).