# How to rename outputFileName for androidTest.apk?

Tags: android, testing, gradle, build, instrumentation

After searching 2 days on the internet I wasn't able to find a way to rename the output file name of android-test.apk (for instrumented tests). I am building debug and instrumented tests apk with assembleAndroidTest and assembleDebug.

For debug build I managed to change the name and add version, but I couldn't do it for androidTest.apk. How can I add the same version and other name for test apk?
Here is my build.gradle (module)

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    project.archivesBaseName = "Automator"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.automator"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def appName = "Automator"
                    outputFileName = appName + "-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Andrei Morosan refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678398/change-generated-apk-name-from-app-debug-apk) may it will help you.

Comment: @NileshPanchal I already used that for debug and release build. But I couldn't find a way to do it for instrumented tests.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#change-the-test-build-type) can help you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also facing this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Because I want to generate separate names at build time. One name for debug/release and another name for instrumented tests.

Answer (score 6):

Add this code to your app `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // Make custom APK name for test builds
    testVariants.all { testVariant ->
        testVariant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "CustomNameTest.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the following code in your app 'build.gradle' file

```
android {

buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "Your_Desired_Name.apk"
            }
        }
}
```

This will work with latest sdk as well as latest os version.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. Because I want to generate separate names at build time. One name for debug/release and another name for instrumented tests.